# Segmentation fault while using std::uniform_int_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random, gcc-warning

I am hitting Segmentation fault while in the below program. Compilation work fine.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 19);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Below is the error

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::operator()<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul> > (
    this=0xb10f40, __urng=..., __param=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.tcc:864
864           uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::
```

OS : Debian, gcc version 4.7.2

Let me know if need more information.

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: I tried it's working

Comment: http://ideone.com/9qH8rp succeded. Does it always happen? Maybe certain flag combination triggers it. I.e. optimizations. frame pointer ommiting, fast math...

Comment: Is there any relation with gcc version

Comment: [Works on ideone](http://ideone.com/HpSRZV).  You might see if you can upgrade gcc to a newer version.  Perhaps it was an issue that was fixed.  It's pretty simple code, not much to go wrong.

Comment: @luk32  Yes. it's always happening. Simple run is working fine. But when I am adding this is in tupfile it's failing and from gdb source it's pointing to  c++/4.7 don't you think it should be c++/11.

Comment: 4.7 is gcc version not version of the standard. I don't know what tup is, but I guess it's a build system. Your code is fine as a standalone program, so you can try compiling it by hand and running. If it works, you need to figure out what flags the build system uses and try it again by hand. You don't have any problem in your program, you need to debug the build process and see where it fails.

Comment: Problem solved it was my programming bug.

Comment: @eswaat how did you solve it?

Comment: I have a similar issue, when I supply int32_t as the template parameter and use limits LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX, I get a segmentation fault, similarly for int64_t and LLONG_MIN and LLONG_MAX.

Comment: I got the same problem.  I wrote unit test fine. But when used in a loop I got segmentation fault.  When running under debugger, the same line repeated too many times.  I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days. I will let everyone know when I resolved this problem.

Comment: Also have this exact issue, but on some old public code (which I presume used to work), which makes me suspect that there is an issue with gcc/boost versions